# Reading large csv files in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, large-files

First question here on StackOverFlow.

So, I'm working on a new project and I need to read large CSV-like files from PL/SQL and insert the data into a table. These files are about 400k lines each, and I'm not sure about the best way to do this. My expertise with PL/SQL comes a little short for the task :D

I've seen people using UTL_FILE.FOPEN. Is there a way of reading a large file by chunks or a more appropiate tool to use? I could not find any useful post about this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No need to use pl/sql.  Read up on EXTERNAL TABLES.  You can just configure to load the file as a table and read it with regular SQL selects, etc.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Hey! Thanks for your comment. For some reason, the customer doesn't want to use external tables, and I'm not allowed to do so. Is there any other way? Thanks!

Comment: _"customer doesn't want to use external tables"_    Then I'd be finding out why they put this artificial requirement and see if you can't address their objections.  Another method would be the use of the 'sqlldr' utility, which was designed by oracle specifically for the purpose of loading data from external files into oracle tables.  Really, using pl/sql for this is probably the worst possible way of accomplishing the desired end result.

Comment: @EdStevens Thanks! I'll be talking to them about that requirement, because I don't see the logic there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load data files using an inline external table or APEX_DATA_PARSER. Those techniques are often better than creating external tables because you do not have to manage as many schema objects. And those techniques are often better than using a tool like sqlldr because then your program is not dependent on a specific external program, shell script, or operating system.

### Inline External Table

Find the directory to store the file:

```
select directory_path from all_directories where directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';
```

Create the file test.csv in that directory:

```
Name,Salary
Alice,100
Bob,200
```

Read from that file without creating an external table:

```
select *
from external
(   
    (
        name varchar2(100),
        salary number
    )
    default directory data_pump_dir
    access parameters
    (
        records delimited by newline
        skip 1
        fields terminated by ','
    )
    location ('test.csv')
);
```

Results:

```
NAME    SALARY
-----   ------
Alice   100
Bob     200
```

### APEX_DATA_PARSER

If you have APEX installed on your database, the package `APEX_DATA_PARSER` is a convenient way to query your files. Although this technique does require installing a PL/SQL object that will load the file into a blob. See [this Oracle-Base article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex_data_parser) for the code behind the function `FILE_TO_BLOB`.

```
select col001 name, col002 salary
from table
(
    apex_data_parser.parse
    (
        p_content   => file_to_blob('DATA_PUMP_DIR', 'test.csv'),
        p_file_name => 'test.csv'
    )
)
```

### SQL or PL/SQL?

Although you asked for a PL/SQL solution, the above solutions are mostly SQL only. But that's a good thing if you can even avoid creating PL/SQL objects.

If you're going to use this code inside PL/SQL, it's trivial to put those select statements inside a loop like this:

```
begin
    for lines in
    (
        select *
        from external
        (   
            (
                name varchar2(100),
                salary number
            )
            default directory data_pump_dir
            access parameters
            (
                records delimited by newline
                skip 1
                fields terminated by ','
            )
            location ('test.csv')
        )
    ) loop
        --Do something with the results here.
        dbms_output.put_line('Name: '||lines.name||',Salary: '||lines.salary);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. I ended up using this solution and works perfectly!